# it feels/I feel + as if/like + tense

Tags: tense, subjunctives

Here's an excerpt from a [Daily Mail article](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/femail/article-4056934/Is-selfish-insist-time-year-Meet-women-say-deserve-break-endless-chores-family-festivities.html).

> In the UK, at 58, **I sometimes feel as if I’m on the scrap heap**. As an older woman, **it feels as if people want you to crawl away and patiently await death**. Young people shout at me and speak extra slowly, even though I am not deaf and far from stupid. Social leprosy doesn’t even begin to cover it; for the most part, I feel invisible. But it couldn’t be more different here — older women are not stigmatised.

In this particular context, I selected these two sentences:

> (1a) I sometimes feel as if I am on the scrap heap.
>
> (2a) It feels as if people want you to crawl away and patiently await death.

I'd like to know if the following variations of (1a) and (2a) are possible English in this particular context:

> (1a) I sometimes feel **as if** I **am** on the scrap heap. [Original]
>
> (1b) I sometimes feel **as if** I **was** on the scrap heap.
>
> (1c) I sometimes feel **as if** I **were** on the scrap heap.
>
> (1d) I sometimes feel **like** I **am** on the scrap heap.
>
> (1e) I sometimes feel **like** I **was** on the scrap heap.
>
> (1f) I sometimes feel **like** I **were** on the scrap heap.
>
> (2a) It feels **as if** people **want** you to crawl away and patiently await death. [Original]
>
> (2b) It feels **as if** people **wanted** you to crawl away and patiently await death.
>
> (2c) It feels **like** people **want** you to crawl away and patiently await death.
>
> (2d) It feels **like** people **wanted** you to crawl away and patiently await death.

Answer (score 3):

> (1a) I sometimes feel as if I am on the scrap heap. [Original]

(1b) I sometimes feel as **if I was** on the scrap heap.

- Some Americans, or purists, might object to this structure because they believe it is using the [subjunctive mood](http://writingexplained.org/was-vs-were-difference) incorrectly. But British English people will nearly always use the singular verb, and especially in ***speech***.

(1c) I sometimes feel **as if I were** on the scrap heap.

- Anyone who is a fan of the subjunctive  will prefer this variant. It's also considered to be quite formal, to me it seems a bit odd to insist on formality when you're speaking about being left on the **scrapheap** (I'd spell it as one word too).

The italicised 1d and 1e are also grammatical (many thanks to the OP for reminding me).

Normally, a NOUN should follow verbal expressions such as *look like*, or *feel like*; e.g., *Luke **looks like** his father*. *This jacket **feels like** real leather*

But *feel like I am* can be followed by a prepositional phrase, e.g. [“I feel like I am on an island”](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22feel+like+i+am+on%22&tbm=bks)

(1d) *I sometimes feel like I am on the scrap heap.*

(1e) *I sometimes feel like I was on the scrap heap.*

On the other hand, if we are to believe  Ngram, the (1f) formula **I feel like I were on...** is exceptionally rare

[image]

Curiously, [**Ngram**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=feel+like+I+am+on&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfeel%20like%20I%20am%20on%3B%2Cc0) shows that this type of construction (1d-f) was practically non- existent before the 1950s. If nothing else, it demonstrates that what was once considered unacceptable in writing, is becoming standard in today's  English.

> (2a) It feels as if people want you to crawl away and patiently await death. [Original]

(2b) It feels as if people **wanted** you to crawl away and patiently await death.

- This is perfectly fine. It's using the past tense of the main verb to emphasise, or hint that the speaker is only talking hypothetically.

(2c) It feels **like** people want you to crawl away and patiently await death.

- Perhaps it's dialectal, but in my opinion it's acceptable.

(2d) It feels **like** people **wanted** you to crawl away and patiently await death.

- Idem

Comment: Re "like" versions (1d-f) and (2c-d), you say the latter are acceptable whereas the former "I would not say or write myself". Does that mean the former are not acceptable? If so, how could you explain this ngram: http://goo.gl/uJF9F0

Comment: Thanks for promptly reflecting my comment. But are you sure that (1f), the one with "feel like I were", is grammatical as well? I have presented in my earlier comment to Peter's answer the following ngram: http://goo.gl/iEfX9e (which shows almost non-existent use of "feel like I were" compared to other variations).

Comment: The "were" in (1f) is already in bold. And thanks for doing the research. Oh, and your research could well include the comparison between the present tense and the past subjunctive tense in "as if" and "like" clauses, unless you already know the difference in meaning and usage. I've already been curious about the present tense in "as if" and "like" clause as in the original sentences.

Comment: Wait. Reviewing the ngram (http://goo.gl/iEfX9e) and the examples linked to the ngram, it strikes me that perhaps the examples having the phrase "feel like I was" are not representing the past subjunctive with "was" but simply the past time. What do you think?

Comment: I'm thinking I'm not going to edit the answer a third time. I'm satisfied with it. You cannot expect an answer with  great detail on a question that contains 10 examples.

Answer (score 0):

In our sentences

> feel *as if* = feel *like*

Only using "were" would be incorrect since the subject is *singular* but the verb would be *plural*.

In your second sentence "feels" (present) governs "want" (present)

> It **feels** as if people **want** you...
>   It **felt** as if people **wanted** you...
>   It **felt** as if people **want** you... [might also be possible]

Comment: So are you saying that only (1c) and (1f) are incorrect, and that all the others are correct in the same context?

Comment: Yes, but some people may say it eventhough it's not quite correct.

Comment: According to the following ngram, "feel as if I were" is more popular than "feel as if I was": http://goo.gl/iEfX9e If so, how come (1c) is incorrect?

Comment: @Peter Actually, 'feels like if I were' isn't incorrect, 'were' is most common used when referring to a conditional clause, such as: If I were rich, I would buy one bolt from which we could cross the river, If He were my friend, I would have invited him to my party. 
And about your third suggestion, I'm not sure if using a comparasion clause in the past  with another clause in the present works: 'It felt as if people want you' it doesn't sound correct to me